# How to explicitly link library path via makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, linker

I installed a real-time library **libre** from `brew install libre` in my `macOS`. It is located in the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/libre/0.5.7`. I am trying to explicitly add this path in `Makefile` so I declare `RT_LIBS_PATH=-L/usr/local/Cellar/libre/0.5.7`. The entire makefile looks like this:

```
TARGET = run
LIBS = -O2 -lm
CC = gcc-7
CFLAGS = -fopenmp
RT_LIBS_PATH=-L/usr/local/Cellar/libre/0.5.7/lib


.PHONY: default all clean

all: $(TARGET)

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(RT_LIBS_PATH) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)  -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

However, it seems makefile does not recognize the `libre`, thus I assume I use `RT_LIBS_PATH=-L/usr/local/Cellar/libre/0.5.7/lib` in a wrong way. Kindly, is there something wrong in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specified library path when you are creating .o, you have to specify it when link all objs into executable

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(RT_LIBS_PATH) $(LIBS)  -o $@
```